# Using package datatool in standalone class

Tags: standalone, datatool

I wish to use package datatool in the standalone class (or with the standalone package, whichever works). I want datatool to print each row in the csv file on different page and standalone to crop each pdf according to the content on it (possibly, with fix width).

Following is my MWE. The example runs properly in article class, however, it gives error(s) in the standalone class. I guess that standalone does not like the  clearpage command. However, as per my knowledge, this is the command (or \newpage) that prints each row on different pages in the output PDF.

```
\documentclass{article}%with this class things are fine.
%\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}%this class gives error.

 \usepackage{datatool}
 \DTLloaddb{sample}{sample.csv}%input csv file
 \usepackage{graphicx}

 \begin{document}
   \DTLforeach{sample}{%
      \Nr=Number,\Quote=Quote}{%
    \clearpage

    (\Nr)\Quote
    \begin{center}
      \includegraphics[height=2cm]{test-graphics}
    \end{center}%
  }%
\end{document}
```

The csv file entries are like

```
Number, Quote
 1, Quote 1
 2, {Quote 2 which can have more text than other quotes. Thus, this quote would occupy more space than others would do.}
 3, Quote 3
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I don't think `datatool` is the right tool if you do it this way. I would use a script or Lua to read the file and generate each separate `standalone` document.

Comment: I am not familiar with either script writing or Lua. Could you please direct me to some source to find a appropriate script or a Lua code? BTW, I could get my work done by using a screened package, see http://personal.psu.edu/jcc8//screenread/. Nonetheless, I shall be glad to find out another way as you are suggesting. Thank you in advance!

Comment: It's not clear from your question whether you want a single document (with each page a different size?) or a series of individual documents, one per quote. Since you want to crop to the PDFs to content, I assume the latter.  And does the image file change per quote too?